# mysqli select over two tables - speed optimisation

Tags: mysql

SQL-Select:

```
 SELECT mf.*
      , ma.Titel 
   FROM `sporttype_fragebogen` as mf
      , sporttypen_auswertung as ma 
  WHERE mf.SessionID = ma.SessionID 
  ORDER 
     BY mf.ID
```

In both tabels there are around 17'000 data set. My problem is, that it takes quite long to the the results. How can i speed-optimise my SQL Select?

I also tried with a join, but same "Problem":

```
 SELECT *  
   FROM `sporttype_fragebogen` 
   JOIN sporttypen_auswertung 
     ON sporttype_fragebogen.SessionID = sporttypen_auswertung.SessionID       
  ORDER 
     BY sporttype_fragebogen.ID
```

Thanks for help

Comment: Questions about query performance ALWAYS require, as a minimum, CREATE TABLE statements for ALL relevant tables, and the results of the EXPLAIN for the given query.

Comment: Never use select *.....always provide the name of columns

Comment: Make sure you have indexes on the `sessionID` columns. Other than that, there's nothing you can do to speed it up.

Comment: @Stiller Eugen, you can use partitioning https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/partitioning.html

Comment: @er.irfankhan11 partitioning just for 17000 rows! It's like using "A sledgehammer to crack a nut". Also, partitioning is currently not possible for MyISAM (InnoDB only)